# In Ansible, How to read configMap file in local system and remove it from remote node?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I am having a configMap file in my local system. This configMap is created in kubernetes cluster (which is remote machine). Now i am trying to remove the configMap from remote machine using ansible.

```
   - hosts: k8s
     vars:
       configmap: "./configmap.yml"
       secret: "./secret.yml"

   - name: uninstall configMap file
     shell: "kubectl delete -f {{ configMap }}"
```

The error is as below. Seems it looks for the file in k8s nodes. but the file is there in local machine.

> "stderr": "error: the path \"./configmap.yml\" does not exist"

I also tried this .

```
   - hosts: k8s
     vars:
       configmap: "{{ lookup('file', './configmap.yml') }}"

   - name: get ConfigMap
     shell: "cat {{configmap | from_yaml}} | kubectl delete -f -  "
```

It says changed as if success but the configmap is not removed

How to remove the config map from remote node?

Comment: How about ansible k8s module to remove configmap ? Refer [k8s – Manage Kubernetes (K8s) objects](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_module.html) for more details.

Comment: @DaeinPark It requires remote machine to have openshift which is not available

Comment: I see mixed concepts and the question is not clear to me.
A configMap is a k8s object so you should remove it in K8s.

Are you referring to the configMap or to the manifest that containes the information of the configmap?

Or maybe you are referring to the configMap mounted on the pods deployed?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to understand the issue is checking current directory for the playbook. Compare current directory and directory where you saved the file. They are different. To take current directory:

```
- shell: "pwd"
  register: result
- debug:
    var: result
```

It's easier to use absolute path for configmap.yml to create/use files on the host, e.g.:

```
vars:
  configmap: "/root/configmap.yml"
```